# How does the shell generate input for awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

Say I have a file1 containing:

```
1,2,3,4
```

I can use awk to process that file like this;

```
awk -v FS="," '{print $1}' file1
```

Also I can invoke awk with a Here String, meaning I read from stdin:

```
awk -v FS="," '{print $1}' <<<"9,10,11,12"
```

Command 1 yields the result `1` and command `2` yields 9 as expected.

Now say I have a second file2:

```
4,5
```

If I parse both files with awk sequentally:

```
awk -v FS="," '{print $1}' file1 file2
```

I get:

```
1
4
```

as expected.

But if I'm mixing reading from stdin **and** reading from files, the content I'm reading from stdin gets ignored and only the content in the files get processed sequentially:

```
awk -v FS="," '{print $1}' file1 file2 <<<"9,10,11,12"
awk -v FS="," '{print $1}' file1 <<<"9,10,11,12" file2
awk -v FS="," '{print $1}' <<<"9,10,11,12" file1 file2
```

All three commands yield:

```
1
4
```

which means the content from stdin simply gets thrown away. Now what is the shell doing?

Interestingly if I change command 3 to:

```
awk -v FS="," '{print $1}' <<<"9,10,11,12",file1,file2
```

I simply get `9` , which makes sense, as file1/2 are just two more fields from stdin. But why is then

```
awk -v FS="," '{print $1}' <<<"9,10,11,12" file1 file2
```

not expanded to

```
awk -v FS="," '{print $1}' <<<"9,10,11,12 file1 file2"
```

which would also yield the result `9`?

And why does the content from  stdin gets ignored? The same question arises for command 1 and 2. What is the shell doing here?

I tried out the commands on: GNU bash, version 4.2.53(1)-release

Comment: what are you trying to do? You are asking and answering your own questions!

Comment: **The general question is**:
How does the shell generate input for awk?

**The specific part is**:
But why is then

awk -v FS="," '{print $1}' <<<"9,10,11,12" file1 file2

not expanded to

awk -v FS="," '{print $1}' <<<"9,10,11,12 file1 file2"

which would also yield the result 9?

Comment: note that (at least) `ksh` cmd-line processing will substitute your `<<<"str"` input where you need it by specifing "read-from-std-in via the `-` char", i.e. `awk '{print $1}' file1 - <<<"str" file2`. I would expect this to work in other shells too. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, that worked in GNU bash. I'm wondering why the answer from user3589054 got 2 upvotes, it's completely useless and not helpful

Comment: I don't think you have read [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) . S.O. is about helping people solve problems, its not really here to explain every wrinkle in every programming language (unless it can be framed as a coding problem). Yours, while interesting, doesn't really seem like your project is hung up because of this issue. You'll see comments like "don't tell me how you built the watch, what are you trying to do?" all the time, so get used to it ;-) OK ;-)?

Comment: And please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) at your earliest convenience. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: No big deal. I was just wondering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard input and input from files don't mix together well. This behavior is not exclusive to `awk`, you will find it in a lot of command line applications. It is logical if you think of it like this:

Files need to be processed one by one. The consuming application does not have control over when the input behind STDIN starts and stops. Look at `echo a,b,c | awk -F, '{print $1}' file1 file2`. In what order do the incoming "files" need to be read? When If you think about when `FNR` would need to be reset, or what `FILENAME` should be, it becomes clear that it is hard to make this right.

One trick that you can play, is to let `awk` (or any other program) read from a file descriptor generated by the shell. `awk -F, '{print $1}' file1 <(echo 4,5,6) file2` will do what you expected in the first place.

What happens here, is that a proper file descriptor is created with the `<(...)` syntax (say: `/proc/self/fd/11`), and the reading program can treat it just like a file. It is the second argument, so it is the second file. `FNR` and `FILENAME` are all clear what they should be.

Comment: Thanks for the explenation 'awk -F, '{print $1}' file1 <(echo 4,5,6) file2' worked as well. So in essence, that means, if you mix reading from stdin and from files the shell respectively awk yields undefined behavior. So to make it deterministic, you have to make the input consistent, meaning everything is read in via file descriptors?

Comment: That is my understanding, FloHe.